# Generate random ROWID

Tags: oracle, random, plsql, rowid

I'm trying to create a random ROWID for testing purposes. I know it's not the way to go, but since I have no data (yet) I just need to guarantee when inserting the "value" of the ROWID (using `ROWIDTOCHAR` function) I have a different string everytime.

I've been reading [DBMS_ROWID](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_rowid.htm#CIHEDIFC) from Oracle documentation and I've found a way to generate a ROWID for testing purposes using the `ROWID_CREATE` function.

```
DBMS_ROWID.ROWID_CREATE (
   rowid_type    IN NUMBER, 
   object_number IN NUMBER,
   relative_fno  IN NUMBER,
   block_number  IN NUMBER,
   row_number    IN NUMBER) 
  RETURN ROWID;
```

My question is: Is there a way to instantiate a random ROWID using this funcion? (Like a random function to generate the IN parameters)

Accordingly to what I've read in the [DBMS_RANDOM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_random.htm#CDEJAHCB) page

> - DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM produces integers in [-2^^31, 2^^31).
> - DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE produces numbers in [0,1) with 38 digits of precision.

And I'm not sure if the generated values are always valid to be IN parameters and generate a ROWID. I just need a valid ROWID so I can use the `ROWIDTOCHAR` function

Comment: You can't create a "random ROWID" - a ROWID is the **physical location** of a row inside a tablespace. What do you plan to do with a random location that probably not even points to a valid row? Or maybe to a row from a different table? What exactly is the underlying problem you are trying to solve with that?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to get the real ROWID of a random row from a real table (e.g. SYS.OBJ$, if you don't have your own data yet)? (Storing a ROWID seems odd anyway; [but is usually safe](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:122614800346142639))

Comment: I have a Type and one of it's attributes is a rowid. That rowid value will be inserted in a table. I just need a random ROWID value so it can "pass" the `ROWIDTOCHAR` function. Thanks Alex. I'll try that, make it an awnser so I can accept it. I know it's odd, but I'm not the one designing the architecture :x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than generate your own random value, which may or may not point to an actual object (but probably not), you could get the real ROWID of a random row from a real table. If you don't have your own data you could use any table you can see; look in `all_tables` for the highest `num_rows` value.

As an example you could use `SYS.OBJ$`, if you have priviliges to query that directly:

```
select rowidtochar(min(rowid)) from SYS.OBJ$ sample(0.001);
```

Adjust the sample size so you always get some data, but as little as possible; you'll still get multiple rows back, so the `min()` picks one. It's not guaranteed to get a different value every time of course, but neither is `dbms_random`, and with a big enough table it should be good enough.

---

If you don't have access to a suitably large table, you can generate random values as you described:

```
select rowidtochar(dbms_rowid.rowid_create(
   rowid_type => 1, 
   object_number => ceil(dbms_random.value(0, 1023)),
   relative_fno => ceil(dbms_random.value(0, 1023)),
   block_number => ceil(dbms_random.value(0, 1023)),
   row_number => ceil(dbms_random.value(0, 1023))))
from dual;
```

For each of the integer values this is using the overloaded `dbms_random.value` function to get a value in a range, and then using `ceil` to make it an integer. (You could also trunc, or round, or cast; zero may not be a valid argument though, so you may need the value range to start from one instead with those).

As David Aldridge said there will be limits to some of those arguments (which you may be able to infer from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50998) but they aren't validated beyond that; and running repeatedly gives different values:

```
ROWIDTOCHAR(DBMS_R
------------------
AAAAODADcAAAAOfABa
AAAAHTADOAAAANaAEb
AAAAI+ANtAAAAMuAKl
AAAAOdAI2AAAAMiAJ4
AAAADNAFAAAAAJRAIn
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the function is pretty dumb, in that it is not going to check that a particular object number exists as part of generating the the ROWID. The same might not be true for the rowid_type though.

There is going to be an upper bound on many of the numbers of course, but you could infer those from the ROW ID documentation which explains the format.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more for DBAs. For example when you face problems with datafile corruptions. Tools like `dbv` or statement `alter database dump block` or various database crash dumps contain database block address and the other numbers to be passed to this function. So this can be used to spot particular data in the database.

This function does not check whether the resulting number really addressees a valid row within particular data segment.

If you want to see some random table data use [sample clause:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2065953)

```
select * from t sample(5);
```